# A q-analogue of Ramanujan's tau function

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms, q-analogs

There have been a couple of questions on Ramanujan's $\tau$ function.
[Lehmer's conjecture for Ramanujan's tau function](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32620/)
[The Vanishing of Ramanujan's Function tau(n)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31058/)

A $q$-analogue is given by
$$ \tau_q(n) = \sum_{|\lambda|=n}\prod_{(i,j)}
\frac{[5-h(i,j)][5+h(i,j)]}{[h(i,j)]^2} $$

Here $[k]=\frac{q^k-q^{-k}}{q-q^{-1}}$. The sum is over all partitions of $n$.
The product is over all boxes in the diagram of $\lambda$ and $h(i,j)$ is the hook length of the box $(i,j)$.

This is a $q$-analogue because (despite appearances) it is a Laurent polynomial in $q$ and substituting $q=1$ gives $\tau(n)$.

It would be ridiculous to ask if this is $q$-holonomic.

Is this $q$-analogue known? and does it have any significance in number theory?

Comment: Bruce, wouldn't q-holonomicity imply holonomicity of the $\tau$ sequence?

Comment: Wadim, I guess so. Is that known to fail? 

Answer (score 4):

I am not very well familiar with the notion "$q$-holonomic" but learned it quite recently from [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23437/). If the sequence $\tau_q(n)$ were $q$-holonomic, then $\tau(n)$  would be [holonomic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonomic). The latter means that $$\Delta(x)=x\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1-x^n)^{24}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\tau(k)x^k$$ satisfies a linear differential equation with rational function coefficients. However, this is known to be false: the function $\Delta(x)$ has singularities at all roots of unity.

Note that the function $\Delta(x)$ satisfies an algebraic differential equation with constant coefficients; the result due to Halphen (and independently, although later, by Ramanujan).

Comment: That's interesting to know. It's what I expected. I was really asking if the $q$-analogue had any significance in number theory.

Comment: Sorry. My question didn't make that clear and has been changed.

Comment: Bruce, I learn on the $q$-analogue from your question! I was always convinced that modular forms, like $\Delta(x)$, have no reasonable $q$-analogues, as they are themselves "from the $q$-world" (this has to be understood as they come as special cases of basic hypergeometric series). Your $\tau_q$ beats me. Thanks for this example!

Comment: As for the change, I've never seen $q$-analogues of sequences which come as coefficients of modular forms.